# CURL sending XML without spaces PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl

```
$xmlVariable = '<function name="AddFinancial">
              <component name="people">
              <property name="ppl_id"><![CDATA[34234424]]></property>
              </component>
              <component name="bankpayment">
              <property name="tlog_comment"><![CDATA[CURL, order ID: 242344]]>
              </property> <property name="tlog_evtt_id"><![CDATA[bpm]]></property>
              <property name="tlog_debit"><![CDATA[0]]></property>
              <property name="tlog_credit"><![CDATA[2.00]]></property>
              </component>
              </function>';

              $headers = array();
              $headers[] = 'Accept: application/xml';
              $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/xml';

              $ch = curl_init();
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://test.testmanager.eu/API/Addfin.asp?api_license=234234");
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "input_XML=".$xmlVariable);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0'); 

              $exe  = curl_exec($ch);
              $getInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

The above CURL sends the XML to the URL but somehow removes all the spaces.

```
<functionname="AddFinancial"><componentname="people"><propertyname="ppl_id"><![CDATA[8DFB5500-6134-4220-9DB9-6FF841372C26]]></property></component><componentname="bankpayment"><propertyname="tlog_comment"><![CDATA[CURL,orderID:]]></property><propertyname="tlog_evtt_id"><![CDATA[bpm]]></property><propertyname="tlog_debit"><![CDATA[0]]></property><propertyname="tlog_credit"><![CDATA[2.00]]></property></component></function>
```

`<functionname="AddFinancial">` should be `<function name="AddFinancial">`
If tried using differt headers but until now nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: Check out [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: use `SimpleXMLElement` and use `$node->addAttribute('type', 'stars');` for node's attribute. See more detail http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addattribute.php

Comment: I would ask why do you want those new lines in the xml? The lack of that formatting shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: how do you know that it's sending it without spaces?

Comment: Thanks, ill give thoose options a try. @hassan i contacted the guys who created the API and they checked the logs and told me thats the reason why its not parsing trough.

Comment: XML should parse fine with our without whitespace, so if their failing to parse because of no spaces then their xml parser sucks.  But having `Content-Type: application/xml` and then `input_XML=$xmlVariable` seems contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solutions

Check for example: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29015381/CURL-sending-XML-without-spaces-PHP.html?anchor=a42087921&notificationFollowed=187278980#a42087921